# JWT Authorization Over Socket.io Connection

Tags: node.js, authentication, socket.io, jwt

The fact that I haven't found an existing answer for this makes me think I'm asking the wrong question.  Please feel free to (gently or otherwise) push me onto a better path if necessary.

We use a dedicated auth server, the purpose of which is to (1) given login credentials, return a JWT with a near-term `exp` or (2) given a JWT, according to a set of rules, issue a new JWT.  A refresh, essentially.

That all works ace, until it's hacked.  But for now, it's ace.

When it comes to `socket.io` connections to non-auth servers, however, we're shooting more than a bit from the hip.  I wonder if somebody would be so kind as to evaluate this process.  (I'm happy to post more code; you tell me if it's relevant).

1) initial `socket.io` connection results in a challenge:

```
this.socket.emit('authenticate'); // the challenge

this.authTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
  this.socket.disconnect('unauthorized', errors);
}, TIME_TO_AUTHENTICATE); // the response kills this!

this.socket.on('authenticate', token => {
  clearTimeout(this.authTimeout);
  this._authenticate(token)
})
```

2) subsequent messages must contain a "payload" message in the form:
`payload = {token: 'foo', message: 'bar'}`, which token would be accepted if valid or returned if invalid.

In addition, the resource server sends its own periodic `heartbeat`, which must be acknowledged by `heartbeat {token}`.

My question, thus is: this seems too easy; am I cutting corners somewhere?  Could you defeat this feeble fortification?

Just to be clear, we're looking to roll our own module here.  I'm happy to look at anything existing; just haven't found anything I could begin to convince the bosses is fully baked for our needs.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot fully analyse the method or ensure it doesn't have flaws, however I'd like to point out some things that came up to mind:

- Apart from disconnecting the user in case of timeout on authentication challenge, you must ensure that the server does not send any non-public message to this user until after the authorization challenge is actually fulfilled successfully. Otherwise, there is a period until timeout where the user could receive a message without being authenticated.
- I assume that you are also disconnecting the socket if token is invalid (or someway preventing non-public message to be sent).
- [This article](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/15/auth-with-socket-io/) is about authenticating socket.io communications using JWT. It is from 2014 so it might be a little bit out of date but I think that the core concept is still valid.
- Associated with the article, there is a tool built specifically to authenticate socket.io connections using jwt. Even if you don't want to use it, you might want to explore its code looking for "inspiration". You can find it here: [socketio-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt).

You can see that this tool is able to use two different approaches:

1. An approach pretty similar to yours:

from socketio-jwt/blob/master/lib/index.js

```
if(options.required){
  var auth_timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    socket.disconnect('unauthorized');
  }, options.timeout || 5000);
}

socket.on('authenticate', function (data) {
  // ...
  // Token validation

  // Emit "authenticated" event if token is valid, the server can use
  // this event as a point to send messages, once token is valid
});
```

2. A "One roundtrip" approach that basically uses query strings during handshake. And whose main drawback is that the token is exposed in the URL, so it might be logged, or getting exposed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and apologies for taking so long to accept the answer.  Holidays, etc.  I'll dive more into the socketio-jwt library, as it seems, like you said, to be similar to mine, albeit much more mature.